# Prevent clicking twice before running indented if block

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I want to check if my class contains a certain class name before running my indented if statment,
my problem is that I'm required to press my button twice before it runs my indented `if and else` statements while I just want to press it once.

my code :

```js
filter(e) {

    if (e.target.classList.contains(productive)) {
        if (document.getElementById(productive).style.display === "block") {
            document.getElementById(productive).style.display = "none"
            e.target.classList.add('selected');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(productive).style.display = "block"
            e.target.classList.remove('selected');
        }
    }

}
```

this is how I have attached my onclick

```php
<div id="filter_"><a className={""+main_class} style={pillStyle} onClick={this.filter}>{this.props.filter}</a></div>
```

Comment: The problem is where you're attaching the click event to the button, not in this code you've shown. Please add the _relevant_ code to the question.

Comment: Okay, so what you need to do is store the ID of the element clicked and then have a timeout for this element, then just add an if statement to check it was double clicked

Comment: Just seen your update, why not change onclick to ondblclick

Comment: How are the placeholders in `onclick` rendered? For now, this is a client-side problem, we need to see the code the browsers see when executing the code, the server-side template is not useful.

Comment: @krisph It looks like OP has a problem with the event firing, they want to fire it with a single click, but they've to click twice to trigger the event. "Required" here doesn't refer to a boss'es or client's requirement, rather the page forces OP to click twice before the event fires. Or, I've misunderstood the question totally ...

Comment: Please copy from the browser development tools the `div.filter_` to that question. The PHP isn't necessary...